# Where can I download the Exchange 2010 Management Console for Windows 7?

Tags: exchange-2010

Everything I read online says to install it via the installation DVD.  What if I don't have that? This was installed on a server in a different office and I don't have it here, but I need to install the management console on my local machine.

Is there somewhere online I can download this from? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I found the answer [here](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-install-management-tools).

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as accepted. It lets the system know that an answer was found, and make sure it doesn't get recycled.

Comment: Yeah...I had to wait long enough to be able to accept my own answer is all. Thanks.

Comment: Take care with the server versión, if not the same, the console will not work and give you a warning message about versions difference between client and server!!!
Look for installed ServicePack and UpdateRollUp in your server first!! Here are all versions from Microsoft: [Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/240.exchange-server-and-update-rollup-build-numbers.aspx#H)